# How to concatenate strings in twig

Tags: syntax, twig, string-concatenation, templating

Anyone knows how to concatenate strings in twig? I want to do something like:

```
{{ concat('http://', app.request.host) }}
```

Answer (score 1045, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
{{ 'http://' ~ app.request.host }}
```

To add a filter - like 'trans' - in the same tag use

```
{{ ('http://' ~ app.request.host) | trans }}
```

As [Adam Elsodaney points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24693583/133717), you can also use [string interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/templates.html#string-interpolation), this does require double quoted strings:

```
{{ "http://#{app.request.host}" }}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But it appears that | trans filter doesn't work on that (eg: {{ 'test_' ~ name | trans }} won't translate my items. Do you have an idea how to do that? thx!

Comment: Yes, you have to create a variable to hold the concatenated string. E.g.: ```{% set foo = 'http://' ~ app.request.host %}```. And then you can do: ```{{ foo | trans }}```.

Comment: Translation in one line: {{ ('test_' ~ name) | trans }}

Comment: Thank you. So the problem is that filters have higher precedence than the concatenation operator.

Comment: This worked for me to concat strings passed into a function as one argument, with filters on the variable and the function token itself: `{{ form_open('admin/files/?path='~file_path|urlencode)|raw }}` No need for an extra variable.

Comment: Thanks for your post!! It did save me much time solving this issue.

Comment: Thank you! Wrapping the concatenation in parenthesis helped with trans.

Comment: Please note, that the hash-sign must be before the open curly brace to make it interpolate. Also it must be double quotes.

Answer (score 118):

Also a little known feature in Twig is [string interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#string-interpolation):

```
{{ "http://#{app.request.host}" }}
```

Comment: Nice feature. Be aware, double-quoted strings only!

Answer (score 33):

The operator you are looking for is Tilde (~), like Alessandro said, and here it is in the documentation:

> ~: Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them. {{ "Hello
> " ~ name ~ "!" }} would return (assuming name is 'John') Hello John!. –  *http://twig.symfony.com/doc/templates.html#other-operators*

And here is an example [somewhere else in the docs](http://twig.symfony.com/doc/templates.html#expressions):

```
{% set greeting = 'Hello' %}
{% set name = 'Fabien' %}

{{ greeting ~ name|lower }}   {# Hello fabien #}

{# use parenthesis to change precedence #}
{{ (greeting ~ name)|lower }} {# hello fabien #}
```

Answer (score 22):

In this case, where you want to output plain text and a variable, you could do it like this:

```
http://{{ app.request.host }}
```

If you want to concatenate some variables, alessandro1997's solution would be much better.

Comment: this does not work for me, cause i have to url_encode the whole string with another filter...

Answer (score 16):

```
{{ ['foo', 'bar'|capitalize]|join }}
```

As you can see this works with filters and functions without needing to use `set` on a seperate line.

Answer (score 12):

Whenever you need to use a filter with a concatenated string (or a basic math operation) you should wrap it with ()'s. Eg.:

`{{ ('http://' ~ app.request.host) | url_encode }}`

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I needed to concatenate variables for use as a translation key.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `~` like `{{ foo ~ 'inline string' ~ bar.fieldName }}`

But you can also create your own `concat` function to use it like in your question:
`{{ concat('http://', app.request.host) }}`:

In `src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('concat', [$this, 'concat'], ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
        ];
    }

    public function concat()
    {
        return implode('', func_get_args())
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

In `app/config/services.yml`:

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Answer (score 6):

In Symfony you can use this for protocol and host:

```
{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost }}
```

Though @alessandro1997 gave a perfect answer about concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- Twig string concatenation may also be done with the `format()` filter

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- Twig 2.x
- String building and concatenation

#### Problem

- **Scenario:** DeveloperGailSim wishes to do string concatenation in Twig

  - Other answers in this thread already address the concat operator
  - This answer focuses on the `format` filter which is more expressive

#### Solution

- Alternative approach is to use the `format` filter
- The `format` filter works like the `sprintf` function in other programming languages
- The `format` filter may be less cumbersome than the ~ operator for more complex strings

#### Example00

- example00 string concat bare

  ```
    {{ "%s%s%s!"|format('alpha','bravo','charlie') }}

    --- result --

    alphabravocharlie!
  ```

#### Example01

- example01 string concat with intervening text

  ```
    {{ "The %s in %s falls mainly on the %s!"|format('alpha','bravo','charlie') }}

    --- result --

    The alpha in bravo falls mainly on the charlie!
  ```

#### Example02

- example02 string concat with numeric formatting
- follows the same syntax as `sprintf` in other languages

  ```
    {{ "The %04d in %04d falls mainly on the %s!"|format(2,3,'tree') }}

    --- result --

    The 0002 in 0003 falls mainly on the tree!
  ```

#### See also

- http://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/printf/info

Answer (score 3):

To mix strings, variables and translations I simply do the following:

```
    {% set add_link = '
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-icon-only" 
       title="' ~ 'string.to_be_translated'|trans ~ '" 
       href="' ~ path('acme_myBundle_link',{'link':link.id})  ~ '">
    </a>
    ' %}
```

Despite everything being mixed up, it works like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

The "{{ ... }}"-delimiter can also be used within strings:

```
"http://{{ app.request.host }}"
```