# Convert variable to string in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm having trouble to translate a string in Twig. I'm building a theme for a multilingual webshop.

A user can create a USP (Unique Selling Point). Problem is that it won't translate when you have a different language.

So the usp is called like this in the template `{{ theme.usp }}`
The outcome of that is for example "Free shipping".

To translate a string in the system you have to use a `{{ 'Free shipping' | t }}` filter.

Is there any way to get `{{ theme.usp }}` translated. I thought this would be useful but I don't know how to incorporate this. [How to concatenate strings in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig)

What I did was:

```
{% set usp = {{ theme.usp }} %}
{{ usp | t }}
```

Doing this gives me an error since `{{ theme.usp }}` has to be between `''`. Doing that doesn't gives me `'Free shipping'` as outcome but `'theme.usp'`.

Anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
{{ theme.usp|trans }}
```

or if it must be filtered by `t` then

```
{{ theme.usp|t  }}
```

Comment: Yes i tried that. Doesn't give the desired result. I think it's more about transforming {{ theme.usp }} to an object which then can be translated with a 't' function??

Comment: is `theme.usp` an object or a string?

Answer (score 7):

Easy way to do this is to use one of filters (which are in fact PHP functions at the end) that simply returns string as in PHP docs.

For example, I had a problem with explicitly setting a value in a *choice* (SELECT/OPTION) form type, as it required a string, but I got an int as a value. I simply did this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.scope, {'value': scope|trim}) }}
```

scope was int, but trim (and other PHP functions, here as Twig filters) automatically makes it a string. Yeah, it's another missing functionality in Symfony2, btw.

Answer (score -5):

Try this

```
{{ usp|print_r }}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: `Print_r` isn't in the doc https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/