# Twig concatenation in assets

Tags: php, symfony, twig

This works just fine:

```
   {% image '@TestBundle/Resources/pic2/image.jpg' %} 
       <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
   {% endimage %}
```

but I need to make it more dynamic by displaying the name of uploaded image instead of image.jpg. I need somehow to concatenate the asset with `{{ entity.picture }}`

Is there any way to do this in twig without getting an error of course?

```
{% image '@TestBundle/Resources/pic2/' . {{ entity.picture }} %}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate strings in twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig)

Comment: @Chausser, not really. I checked that post before I opened this and is something else. I need the concatenation done for the asset. Anyway, that don't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
// config.yml add a global variable (Or just assign the path from the controller)
twig:
    globals:
        imagepath: "your/path/to/thepictures/"
```

I don't this this works in twig since this image is used for [assets optimization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/jpeg_optimize.html):

```
{% image {{ imagepath ~ entity.picture }} %}
```

So an alternative can be:

```
<img src="{{ imagepath ~ entity.picture }}">
```