# Symfony2 - twig concatenation in Assetic

Tags: php, symfony, concatenation, assetic

There already exist similar questions ([concatenation in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig), [concatenation in Assetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138651/twig-concatenation-in-assets)), but it is not helping me.

I am trying to display an image from the path and image name passed from controller:

```
{% image 'bundles/index/uploads/logos/' ~ fileName %}
<img src="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endimage %}
```

And I am getting an error:

```
Unexpected token "operator" of value "~"
```

How to overcome this issue? It seems that concatenation is not allowed in `{% image %}`

P.S.

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/index/uploads/logos/' ~ university.getLogo) }}" />
```

This works fine, but I am up to Assetic due filter and output management.

Comment: Never saw the `image` tag, what about `{% image ('bundles/index/uploads/logos/' ~ fileName) %}`

Comment: @Rvanlaak not working

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `image` tag? Did never see it before: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation

Answer (score 0):

You should define your image filter as a Twig function & when use it. For example (code used from documenation)

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
  filters:
      jpegoptim:
          bin: path/to/jpegoptim
  twig:
      functions:
          jpegoptim: ~
```

In your twig template:

```
<img src="{{ jpegoptim('@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/' ~ fileName) }}" alt="Example"/>
```

You can find more info in Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/jpeg_optimize.html#shorter-syntax-twig-function