# Twig: How to concat and translate strings?

Tags: php, string, symfony, twig, yaml

I tried the [answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig), but it's not working. It's weird and I cannot reproduce the behavior:

- I cleared the cache
- Concat works (it output's the right string)
- The concated string as a variable is not translateable
- The concated string pasted as a string is translateable
- **Edit**: `obj2arr` casts the object to an array, to make it iterable. `prepareForTwig` is just using `trim()`, etc. - the string is outputted correctly.
- **Edit 2**: `{% set transVar = (key|prepareForTwig) %}` (without prefix) doesn't work as well.

**yml:**

```
# Resources/translations/messages.en.yml
my:
   keywords:
       keyword1: K1
       keyword2: K2
       # ...
```

**twig:**

```
{# my.twig.html #}
{% for key, value in data|obj2arr %}
    {% set transVar = 'my.keywords.' ~ (key|prepareForTwig)) %}

    {{ transVar }}<br/>                    {# output, e.g.: my.keywords.keyword1 #}
    {{ transVar|trans}}<br/>               {# output, e.g.: my.keywords.keyword1 #}  
    {{ 'my.keywords.keyword1'|trans }}     {# output: K1 #}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:**

**CustomTwigExtension.php**

```
class CustomTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('obj2arr', array($this, 'obj2arrFilter')),
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('prepareForTwig', array($this, 'prepareForTwigFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function obj2arrFilter($obj)
    {
        return (array)$obj;
    }

    public function prepareForTwigFilter($str) {
        $str = trim($str);
        $str = strtolower($str);
        $str = substr($str, 2, strlen($str)); // obj2arr() prefixes "*"

        return $str;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'custom_twig_extension';
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried using parentesis, like `{{ (transVar) | trans }}`?

Comment: @Artamiel Yes, I tried, thanks. Unfortunately same result.

Comment: Be sure to check twice. I myself tried it right now with `{{ ('hello.world.' ~ myVar) | trans }}` where `myVar` is set to `'message'` and it got translated correctly.

Comment: @Artamiel The problem is not the syntax, I guess. If I paste the concated string, it works. Maybe `obj2arr` and `prepareForTwig` are responsible for the weird issue. But I have no idea how this could affect the translation. The outputted, concated string is right.

Comment: The issue happens because you are trying to have twig evaluate a variable and then use it as a twig construct. This is usally not available, but you can make it work using Twig's template_from_string function: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html

Comment: @CarlosGranados I tried `{{ include(template_from_string("{{ transVar|trans }}")) }}` - same result as above. Did you mean it this way?

Comment: What happens if you try it this way - `{% set transVar = key | prepareForTwig %}` and then output it like `{{ 'my.keywords.' ~ transVar | trans }}`

Comment: Use {{ include(template_from_string("{{ '" ~ transVar ~ "'|trans }}")) }}

Comment: @Artamiel same result. There must be any black magic bug.

Comment: @CarlosGranados same result as well.

Comment: This last solution should work. Have you copied it exactly as I input it? Notice that there is a ' character within the " character, it is not easy to see.

Comment: Also, did you activate the template_from_string function? It is not active by default

Comment: You custom twig extension has nothing to do with this problem

Comment: @CarlosGranados Yes, I copied your code and activated the function. I just added the code of my custom twig extension. Maybe there's anything wrong (unlikely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every **answer** of outputting concated translationstrings was right, example:

```
{% 'my.prefix.' ~ extendByKeyword | trans }}
```

The **problem was** a weird generated space:

- `(array) $obj` added `*` *(there are two spaces after the star)* as a prefix to the `key`-variable.
- I used `substr()` to get rid of the `*` *(star + 1 space)*, but didn't notice/expect the second space.
- After comparing the strings with `strlen()`, I found the cause.

Thanks to @Artamiel and @CarlosGranados for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Others examples didn't seem to work in my case, this is what I ended up using:

```
{{ "my.prefix.#{ myVariable }.my.postfix" | trans }}
```

The translation string has to be between double quotes.

Comment: Just a small note, opening brackets should be ```{{``` not ```{%```