# How to have a nested array value in Twig Template

Tags: php, twig, slim

This seems like a hard question to ask, but here goes.

I am using: Slim2 / Twig / Symfony Translation

My lang file has:

```
['billdata' =>
    [
        '0' => 'EU Basic',
        '1' => 'USA',
        '2' => 'internal'
    ]
]
```

Then, I need a loop in my template. 
`{{plan.alias}}` is the "1","2" so on, in the lang file. If I write `{{billdata.1|trans}}` it works. How do I get the "plan.alias" into that so it runs through translation engine?
`{{billdata.alias|trans}}`

Answer (score 0):

I found this, after trying tens of suggestions:
[How to concatenate strings in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig)

the answer seems to be: 
{{ ('billdata' ~ plan.alias) | trans }}