# Twig & Html concatenation

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I'm looking for a way to get some id like :

`first_1` /  `first_2` / etc etc

But currently i'm doing wrong

```
{% set nb = 0 %}
{% for resultat in resultats %}
    {% if resultat.first == 1 %}
        {% set nb=nb+1 %}
        <tr id="first_"{{ nb }}>
```

This is giving `id="first_"` and an other param `"1"=""`

Thanks for your help

Comment: A little bit of research would have helped you : [how to concatenate in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat string:

```
{% set nb = 0 %}

<tr id="first_{{ nb }}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have:

1. [`loop variables`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)
2. [`String Interpolation`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#string-interpolation)

```js
{{ "first_#{loop.index0}" }}
```

you don't need to manually create the incrementer.

Further info: [How to concatenate strings in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig#7704889)

Answer (score 0):

You can concat string in Twig with "~" (same as "." in php and "+" in javascript)

```
    <tr id="{{ 'first_' ~ nb }}">
```