# Twig error when try to format {$

Tags: php, twig

Try to format that code in twig format:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="email_review_subject_<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" ><?php echo isset(${'email_review_subject_' . $language['language_id']}) ? ${'email_review_subject_' . $language['language_id']} : ''; ?></textarea>
```

So i tried with that format:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="email_review_subject_{{ language['language_id'] }}" >{{ isset({'email_review_subject_' . language.language_id}) ? {'email_review_subject_' . language.language_id} : '' }}</textarea>
```

**Error:**

> Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'A hash key must
>   be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token "punctuation" of value
>   "." ("punctuation" expected with value ":")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as `isset` in `twig`. You also need to access the special variable `_context` if you want use dynamic variables in twig

Some possible solutions,

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="email_review_subject_{{ language['language_id'] }}" >{{ attribute(_context, 'email_review_subject_'~language.language_id)|default('') }}</textarea>

<textarea class="form-control" name="email_review_subject_{{ language['language_id'] }}" >{{ attribute(_context, 'email_review_subject_'~language.language_id) is defined ? attribute(_context, 'email_review_subject_'~language.language_id) : '' }}</textarea>
```

[fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/p8h4wn)

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure you can't use `.` to concatenate strings in Twig. Try `~`, and look here: [How to concatenate strings in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig)

Comment: Have you replaced both concatenations in your code? If so, this error is unlikely because it specifically tells you that you have a period (`.`). If that fails, it might be a problem with using dynamic variable names. Try the attribute function: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html

Comment: I think the problem is here "(${"