# Generate url from parameters

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to realize the following thing: in my parameters.yml I have `uploads_url: http://test.site.com`. It's a URL to Docker container with my images. Next, I have an `entity` with names of this pictures.

I want to generate URL in `twig` like this:

```
background-image: url({{ 'URL from parameters' + 'name of picture from `entity`' }})
```

At present time I have the second part of the previous expression (name of the picture). How can I generate the 1st part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app/config/config.yml

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    globals:
        url: "%url%"
```

app/config/parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    url: 'your_url'
```

official doc [How to Inject Variables into all Templates (i.e. global Variables)](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/templating/global_variables.html)

twig concatenate [How to concatenate strings in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig)

Comment: Are there any variants to do it without "twig globals"?