# How to pass a dynamic variable to a macro inside the assets function?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

is passing a variable to a twig macro inside the assets function even possible, for example it doesn't work with with concatenaciton:

Macro:

```
{% macro card(image) %}
    <div class="card">
        <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/' ~ {{image}} ~ '.svg') }}" alt="" />
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Calling the macro:

```
{{ macros.card('questions.svg'}}
```

Comment: Duplicate of the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig)

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
<img src="{{ asset('assets/images/' ~ image ) }}" alt="" />
```

The double curly braces {{ exampleVariableName }} that are used in twig for variables are not necessary inside the asset function. I think it causes problems with internal interpolation

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: The double curly braces {{ exampleVariableName }} that are used in twig for variables are not necessary inside the asset function. I think it causes problems with internal interpolation.

Comment: The explanation was not for me.  I have added it to your answer.  Your answer is considered low quality by StackOverflow unless it is complete with example, explanation and reference.  I have upvoted it now.

Comment: That explanation is just incorrect though and has nothing to do with interpolation. As pointed out in the question I've linked this is mere a concatenation of two (or more) string. Furthermore, the `{{ ... }}` is used to output content. So this is just a syntactically error, nothing more